# How can i see the li hover w?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem on my heading i want to use a greyscale filter on hover but for some reason the greyscale filter has a bigger importance than my navbar hover li. I searched but no one had this problem :(,
 I want to see the hover li. I know that filters are used in a galley and i used before but i didn't see this problem until now. How can i solve this?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".main-header").toggleClass("grey");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  margin-top: 9px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(192, 190, 190);
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.parent {
  margin-top: 9px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.parent li {
  display: none;
}

.child:hover .parent li {
  display: block;
}

.main-header {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  padding: 50px 0;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.grey {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='styles.css'>

</head>
<!-- header -->

<body>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="child"><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul class="parent">
        <li class="child"><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
        <li class="child"><a href="">Camp Sites</a></li>
        <li class=" child"><a href="">Resources</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="child"><a href="#">Things to do</a>
      <ul class="parent">
        <li class="child"><a href="">Activities</a></li>
        <li class="child"><a href="">Parks</a></li>
        <li class="child"><a href="">Shops</a></li>
        <li class=" child"><a href="">Events</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- header -->
  <div class='main-header'>
    <button>click to turn grey</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `.parent` class on your dropdown menus a z-index of 1:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".main-header").toggleClass("grey");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  margin-top: 9px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

.child {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(192, 190, 190);
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.parent {
  margin-top: 9px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.parent li {
  display: none;
}

.child:hover .parent li {
  display: block;
}

.main-header {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  padding: 50px 0;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.grey {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="child"><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul class="parent">
      <li class="child"><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
      <li class="child"><a href="">Camp Sites</a></li>
      <li class=" child"><a href="">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="child"><a href="#">Things to do</a>
    <ul class="parent">
      <li class="child"><a href="">Activities</a></li>
      <li class="child"><a href="">Parks</a></li>
      <li class="child"><a href="">Shops</a></li>
      <li class=" child"><a href="">Events</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- header -->
<div class='main-header'>
  <button>click to turn grey</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```